# How did Calvin end up there without being seen?

Tags: plot-explanation, life

Big spoiler if you didn't watch the movie:

In [Life](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5442430/) after Hugh gives his speech about Calvin not hating them, they found it curled up in Hugh's leg, inside his suit! How could it end up there without anybody seeing it, except by a large plot hole? When would it have got there?

Comment: I won't use the spoiler markup since the meat of the question includes the spoiler

Comment: "meat". hah hah.

Comment: Hugh allowed it to enter the ship and stay with him with the hope that it may help to cure himself.

Comment: @shahul if you have an answer please use the "Post your answer" button, not a comment. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help].

Answer (score 1):

Hugh has some strange, inexplicable (read : stupid) bond with Calvin from the beginning. He's the only one calling it Calvin, like it's a person. He feels that the world's stem cell research (and possibly healing paraplegic folks like himself) would take a leap ahead because of Calvin.

Calvin has other plans. It wants to consume them. After Calvin enters back from those thrusters .. it makes its way to the group.

ref : [Life (2017) Explained](http://www.thisisbarry.com/single-post/2017/04/02/Life-2017-Movie-Plot-Ending-Explained)

> Let's take a minute and see what Hugh is up to here. Hugh has some
>   crazy affinity with Calvin. He sees Calvin approach while the others
>   are taping up the place. He doesn’t say anything. He actually allows
>   Calvin to latch on to his leg. He then goes on to talk about how the
>   nature of life is through destruction. How Calvin doesn’t hate them
>   but has to kill them for its own survival. He then touches his leg and
>   then begins to lose consciousness. Then he says “I’m sorry”. Hugh's
>   helping Calvin here. He's lost it and the crew doesn't realize this.

(There is a pic of Hugh's hand on his leg too)
So Hugh seems to have allowed this to happen.

Comment: where is this quote from? can you add the source?

Comment: @Luciano sorry, missed the reference link. Added.

Comment: Has anyone noticed that this doesn't actually answer the question asked? "When would it have got there?"  Hugh may well have allowed it to happen, but the question isn't 'why' but 'how.'

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Calvin making his way into Hugh's pants:

As some have already pointed out; Hugh was weak and injured  - he also has some weird affinity with the organism. So yes, it may have been intentional but also remember Hugh hadn't got the use of his legs. Calvin has repeatedly demonstrated a frighteningly high level of intelligence at this point. Messing with Cat's coolant system in her suit. Sho says (during that scene) that "Calvin knows exactly what he's doing!"

So as well as Hugh having no sensation in his legs I'm pretty sure Calvin has the gumption to figure out that crawling UP the leg of the suit is probably the desirable method here.

I mean... he was clever enough to push his escape pod towards earth via mr gyllenhall

Answer (score 0):

After Calvin reentered through the thrusters when no one was looking, Calvin latched onto Hughes's leg. Hughes did not know he was latching onto his leg but the movie had a good misdirection about if he did or not. We all know that Huges is a paraplegic and most vulnerable also because he was the closest to the compartment opening.

Answer (score -1):

There was a scene shortly before, from Calvin's point of view, where he (it?) is tracking Hugh.  Hugh is standing behind the others, who are looking the other way.  Hugh looks up into Calvin's POV, the music surges, and then the scene cuts to a shot of David and Miranda, without Hugh in view. Shortly thereafter, he comes into view and then collapses.  That's when they finally discover Calvin in Hugh's pants.

The implication being that Calvin slipped into Hugh's suit at that point.

As far as why Hugh didn't mention the monster in his pants, it was likely that he was too stunned/drained/sick to mention it. Or he could have just decided not to (since he felt fatherly towards it).

Comment: By his previous behaviour it seems Hugh is so obsessed with Calvin that he would try to defend / save it

Comment: @Luciano Yeah, they made it kind of ambiguous as to whether he was deliberately being quiet about Calvin being in his suit.

Comment: I thought there was some implication that Hugh saw Calvin through the open hatch, ignored it and turned his back on it.  But clearly he didn't mention it on his leg because he didn't feel it - y'know, not having feeling in his legs n'all.

Comment: @Mr_Thyroid Obviously he couldn't feel it on his leg, but you're saying he didn't feel it crawling down the neck of his suit, either?  He HAD to feel it and/or see it at some point.  He might not have known it was eating him, but he had to know it was inside his suit.

Comment: @aryxus I don't know what type of trousers you wear but mine have holes that my feet poke through.  Calvin demonstrated dexterity and intelligence I think we were supposed to assume that Calvin worked out that Hugh could not feel his legs and therefore targeted that part of his body for food by crawling up his trouser leg.

Answer (score -1):

Clearly Calvin enters Hughs' pants the moment you see everything from Calvins' POV.
Whether or not Hugh realizes it at that moment or just a little later on ('cause he sure knows when he's dying) is up to anyones' speculation I guess...

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Movies & TV StackExchange. Thanks for answering the question, but could you elaborate on why this answer is correct and do your best to provide back-up for it? Thanks!